# How to update my staging branch to be an exact copy of main

Tags: git, github, testing, staging

On my deployment workflow I constantly need to make fine testing adjustment in my staging branch, I test things out in there and then open a hotfix branch from main to implement the fix.

The problem is that after merging the hotfix with main I usually end up with a branch history that is incompatible to merge or rebase with my current staging branch.

How can I simply turn my staging branch into a copy of main, without merging?

Comment: Do you have code you want to preserve on the staging branch or do you want them to be literally identical?

Comment: Reset your staging branch to point at the same commit as main? They will then be _absolutely_ identical, including their histories.

Comment: @etchesketch I want them to be literally identical

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your branches to be literally identical you can simply delete your staging branch and create a new "staging" branch from main.

```
git checkout main

git branch -d staging

git branch staging
```